# How to pass args to embedded python sub-interpreter?

Tags: python, interpreter, argv

I need to interpret few files (scripts) by embedded python interpreter concurrently (to be more detailed one script executes another script as `Popen` and my app intercepts it and executes it itself). I've found it's called [sub-interpreter](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#sub-interpreter-support) and i'm going to use it. But i've read sub-interpreter does not have `sys.argv`:

> The new environment has no sys.argv variable

I need to pass argv anyway so how can i do it?

Comment: Well you can't pass argv.  What is the higher-level goal you want to achieve?  I.e. what would you be passing in argv?

Comment: i need to pass some arguments to script (f.e. data filename)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find it easier to modify each of the scripts follow the pattern:

```
def run(*posargs, **argdict):
   """ 
   This does the work and can be called with:
   import scriptname
   scriptname.run(someargs) 
   """
   # Code goes here and uses posargs[n] where it would use sys.argv[n+1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   run(sys.argv[1:])
```

Then your main script can just call each of the subscripts in turn by simply calling the run method.

Comment: It is a pattern that I use all the time when I have a utility script that might be useful programmatically as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables.  Have the parent set them by updating the dict `os.environ` if it's in Python, or `setenv()` if in C or C++ etc.  Then the children can read `os.environ` to get whatever strings they need.

Comment: it seems that os variables should be set before Py_Initialize and they are unknown at that moment

Comment: I think it would help if you were a lot more specific about your situation here.  I'm basically lost at this point in terms of what you're trying to do.